# call express function from client using callable

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

the following method returns *Hello world* when I'm listening on a local port with my browser.

//Node

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
        res.send('Hello world')
        });
```

I've exported the app as a callable cloud function successfully named: `getConstits`

//Node

```
exports.getConstits = functions.https.onCall(app);
```

I then call the function in my client.

//Client

```
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
    functionName: 'getConstits',
);


getElec()async{
    dynamic resp = await callable.call();
    print(resp);
}
```

But I get an unhandled exception(will post if needed). The url generated by the cloud function returns `{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}`. I want to return hello world to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callable functions don't support express apps like regular HTTP functions.

If you want to write an express app and deploy it to Cloud Functions, you'll have to follow the instructions for [express apps with HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps).  If you do this, you will not be able to use the callable function SDK on the client - you will have to use a regular HTTP library instead.

If you want to write a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to invoke with the provided client SDK, you will simply have to write the logic of the function without the help of express, since the callable SDK handles all of the HTTP implementation details.